# print hibernate sql query string with parameters into logs

Tags: java, hibernate

In my hibernate config show_sql property is 'true' and since i am not using log4j API of logging, by default hibernate was showing queries with '?' marks in the tomcat console.

In my case i need to print the complete sql query with parameter values which was executed by hibernate into logs, but i am not using log4j API for logging to configure the debug level for `org.hibernate.SQL` and `org.hibernate.type`.

For logging we are manually writing the content into the file, so in this situation can anybody tell me how can i get the hibernate queries into logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my case i need to print the complete sql query with parameter values which was executed by hibernate into logs, but i am not using log4j API for logging to configure the debug level for `org.hibernate.SQL` and `org.hibernate.type`

Whether you're using a logging framework or not, Hibernate will output question marks when logging prepared statements.

If you want to print the "real query" with the bound values, you'll have to use a JDBC Proxy driver like [P6Spy](http://www.p6spy.com/) (doesn't move anymore) or [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/).

Comment: Even , how can print those sql  statements with question marks into our predefined logs?

Answer (score 0):

As you have asked "To print the sql query with parameters values which was executed by hibernate into logs"

you can set the following parameters into the log4j.properties file

```
#following parameters will be used to log the sql parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
```

It will print the query along with sql parameters along with the datatype .

```
Hibernate: insert into employee (employee_address, employee_name, id) values (?, ?, ?)
11:50:40, 209 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [Address 0]
11:50:40, 209 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [Employee 0]
11:50:40, 209 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [7008]
11:50:40, 210 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] - insert into employee (employee_address, employee_name, id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Please visit this post for more details about code : - http://techpost360.blogspot.in/2016/10/hibernate-show-sql-with-parameter-values.html

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer was given almost 13 years ago. It's been a long time since then and things have changed.
In hibernate `6.1.6.Final`, to get this to work, you must use something like:

```
org.hibernate.SQL: trace
org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind: trace
```

The FQN of the `BasicBinder` class is now `org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.BasicBinder`

Comment: which file exactly?

Comment: In the library with Maven coordinates `org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.1.6.Final`.